# Uniform convergence of $(t+ix)^{-\beta}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-numbers, uniform-convergence

I have a simple direct question that I am not able to solve.
Does the family of complex-valued functions of real variable $x$:
$$g_t(x)=(t+ix)^{-\beta}, \beta>0$$
converge uniformly (w.r.t. x) when $t\to 0^+$?

Comment: What domain you want for $x$? There is a singularity at $x=0$ when $t=0$

Comment: Any bounded closed interval without x=0.

Comment: then one can define a continuous (in both $(t,x)$) logarithm of $t+ix$ for $x \in [a,b], 0 \notin [a,b]$ and $t>-1$ (basically if $a>0$ one defines it uniquely so it is $\log a+i\pi$ at $(0,a)$ and by conjugation if $b<0$) and then $g_t(x)=e^{-\beta \log(t+ix)}$ is a uniformly continuous function in two variables on $[-1,1]\times [a,b]$ and the result clearly holds